# How can create arrays of rows returned by ResultSet ?

Tags: java, mysql

I am still new at java so I wanted to ask for help, I don't really know well how to use square brackets in this situation, no. I don't even really know how to use it, I tried some things and here is the result, my now problem is I want to add:

```
schemeName += (rset.getString("scheme_name"));
schemeId += (Integer.parseInt(rset.getString("id")));
```

but I got an error, because i think i don't use it correctly. Thanks for help and explaining to me how to use it and what's the problem.

all code:

```
String[] schemeName; // TODO, []
Integer[] schemeId; // TODO, []
        String HTML = "";

            Connection conn = null;
            try
            {
                conn = L2DatabaseFactory.getInstance().getConnection();

                PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM buffer_scheme_list WHERE player_id=?");

                statement.setInt(1, player.getObjectId());
                ResultSet rset = statement.executeQuery();

                while (rset.next())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        schemeName += (rset.getString("scheme_name"));
                        schemeId += (Integer.parseInt(rset.getString("id")));
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        // Blank
                    }
                }
            }
```

if I change to:

```
 String schemeNamel
 Integer schemeId;
```

I got in the further code another problem(so i can't do that);
further code:
tried this, but then i got another problem in further code:

```
if (schemeName.length > 0)
                    {
                        String MESSAGE = "";
                        String Temp = "";

                    int i=0, j=0;
                    Temp="<tr><td> </td> <td> </td></tr>";
                    String[] TRS = Temp.split(" ");
                    while (i <= schemeName.length - 1)
                    {
                        if (j>2)
                        {
                            j = 0; // vienas is dvejiu arba if j>2 (&& arba ||), j=0;
                            MESSAGE += TRS[j]+"<button value=\""
                            +schemeName[i]+
                            "\" action=\"bypass -h Quest "+QUEST_LOADING_INFO+" cast "
                            +schemeId[i]+" x x\" width=130 height=25 back=\"L2UI_ct1.button_df\" fore=\"L2UI_ct1.button_df\">"
                            +TRS[j+1];
                        }

                        i+=1;
                        j+=2;
                    }`
```

Comment: show use the stacktrace of your error

Comment: you didnt initialized your array objects and trying to append/add value in it..

Comment: Tell us what you want to achieve, not the (incorrect) method you think you should use.

Comment: I don't know why the downvotes. He mentioned the problem, and everything that he tried

Comment: @Cruncher maybe because of missing stacktrace.

Comment: nope, it's only a part of code i don't really think you need to go througt a 1000 lines of code, i have the stacktrace... Achievment add all Names to list then by their length use their name in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`schemeName` and `schemeId` are Arrays. They don't support `+` operation.

Futhermore didn't you initialize them, so they are still `null`.

I recommend using some kind of Collection like List or Set. They support an `add` Method.

Here's an example using `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<String> schemeName = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> schemeId = new ArrayList<Integer>();

...

schemeName.add((rset.getString("scheme_name"));
schemeId.add(Integer.parseInt(rset.getString("id")));
```

If you prefer working with Arrays afterwards, you can convert the lists to Arrays like this:

```
String[] schemeNameArray= schemeName.toArray(new String[schemeName.size()]);
Integer[] schemeIdArray= schemeId.toArray(new Integer[schemeId.size()]);
```

If `schemeName` and `schemeId` are like value and key use a Map. They support `put`

Comment: yes, that's the problem i am trying ask you how can i use the same method as += in another way in this situation, which will work with arrays?

Comment: with arrays: nothing. because they are not dynamic

Comment: k, thanks i think i will try with list. I already tryied but failed, so let's try again.

Comment: yes i tried this way but in further code i got problem, like this when i need to get schemeName (length) i got array length so there is the problem, i need value.lenght not key.length, yes i can make a loop and try to extract all values.length.

Comment: Thanks i didin't test it but i think it should work with your newest edit, really thanks for help, didin't think you can use array in that way. :)

Answer (score 2):

You have declared an [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

```
String[] schemeName; // TODO, []
Integer[] schemeId; // TODO, []
```

You are trying to **assign value to array**

```
schemeName += (rset.getString("scheme_name"));
schemeId += (Integer.parseInt(rset.getString("id")));
```

You can not do that.

An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of a single type. The length of an array is established when the array is created. After creation, its length is fixed.

Also, you have **not initialized** both the arrays

Comment: In this situation how can i assing example: each "schemeName" from database to String[] schemeName; ?

Comment: Sorry! I read you comment late. Philipp Sander gave nice answer. If you still have problem then post it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include the [] for the String and integers. You can simply declare them as

`String schemeName = "";`

and

`Int schemeId = 0;`